# Making sub-categories in moodle.sty

Tags: moodle

I am trying to use LaTeX with moodle package in order to generate questions for the moodle question bank. In order to change the category of the questions in the same quiz I can use \setcategory. But I cannot find any solution to include a sub-category. I can do this directly in moodle, but it would be easier to do it in LaTeX. I hope there is a solution.

Answer (score 4):

It seems odd that I will answer my own question. But maybe it will be useful for people wanted to keep things organized. I found this solution by chance:

\setcategory{category name / subcategory name}

And it works.

Comment: This works for me also, but when compiling I get a warning `LaTeX Warning: Empty question list on input line 29`. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: The current version of Moodle 4.2 has a control sequence that can set sub-category. `\setcategory{category name}` and `\setsubcategory{subcategory name}`.